# Missing ODBC definition causing Access Query to Fail

Tags: ms-access, odbc

We have a user that is trying to run an Access query on a new laptop and it's failing with an ODBC error.  They obviously don't have the required odbc definition(s) on the new laptop.

How can I get the odbc name the query is using from Access?  We can't figure out what name it's looking for so we can recreate it.

We're using Access for Office 365 MSO.

Comment: Is it a pass-through query, or is it query using ODBC linked tables?

Comment: I believe it's a pass thru query?  Pulling up the properties states, "Type: Query: Select (local)".  I'm a SQL Server guy... I'm an infant when it comes to Access.

Comment: Nope, it's a local query, which means that it pulls information from table definitions in the Access database. In the navigation pane, ODBC linked tables have a "globe" icon and if you mouse over one the tooltip should show you the ODBC connection details (e.g., `ODBC;DSN=myDsnName;...`).

Comment: That's it!  That's exactly what I needed, thank you Mr. Thompson!